# Conditionally print elements in a text file

Tags: perl

I have a text file of the following format:

```
1 4730 1031782 init
4 0 6 events
2190 450 0 top
21413 5928 1 sshd
22355 1970 2009 find
```

I want to print rows of this file only if the second column of data meets the requirement `>= 2000` - how can I do this?

Currently I am reading the file and printing it like so:

```
sub read_file{
  my $data_failed = 1;
  my $file = 'task_file';
  if(open (my $file, "task_file" || die "$!\n")){
    my @COLUMNS = qw( memory cpu program );
    my %sort_strings = ( program => sub { $a cmp $b } );

    my (%process_details, %sort);

    while (<$file>) {
      $data_failed = 0;
      my ($process_id, $memory_size, $cpu_time, $program_name) = split;
      $process_details{$process_id} = { memory  => $memory_size,
                                        cpu     => $cpu_time,
                                        program => $program_name };
      undef $sort{memory}{$memory_size}{$process_id};
      undef $sort{cpu}{$cpu_time}{$process_id};
      undef $sort{program}{$program_name}{$process_id};
    }

    if($option_a == 1){
    if (-z $file){print "No tasks found\n";}
    for my $column ($COLUMNS[2]) {
      my $cmp = $sort_strings{$column} || sub { $a <=> $b };
      for my $value (sort $cmp keys %{ $sort{$column} }
      ) {
          my @pids = keys %{ $sort{$column}{$value} };
          say join ' ', $_, @{ $process_details{$_} }{@COLUMNS}
              for @pids;
        }
      }
    }
  } else { print "No tasks found\n"}
}
```

The `if($option_a == 1)` bit is just reading values from another function that parses command line options.

Comment: `"task_file" || die "$!\n"` makes no sense. That's just `"task_file"`.

Comment: Your `read_file` function overwrites the global `$_` variable. That's bad style.

Comment: @melpomene this is not a "review my code" im just asking for a solution to a problem

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your code doesn't print any rows of the file as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you remove the parts of the code irrelevant to the question?

Comment: @choroba updated

Comment: @DavideLorino: You seem to be drip-feeding us the specification for your program. That seems like a rather inefficient use of everyone's time :-)

Comment: @DaveCross its hard to strike a balance, as you can see from the above, too much information can also be a hindrance

Comment: Code is not a specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my ($process_id, $memory_size, $cpu_time, $program_name) = split;
```

At this point, you can complete the loop, or you can continue to the next line. Just add the line:

```
next if $memory_size < 2000;
```

right after the split, and you'll eliminate all the records in memory that fail to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering a list is easily done with [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };
use warnings;

my @COLUMNS = qw( memory cpu program );

my (%process_details, %sort);

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($process_id, $memory_size, $cpu_time, $program_name) = split;
    $process_details{$process_id} = { memory  => $memory_size,
                                      cpu     => $cpu_time,
                                      program => $program_name };
    undef $sort{memory}{$memory_size}{$process_id};
    undef $sort{cpu}{$cpu_time}{$process_id};
    undef $sort{program}{$program_name}{$process_id};
}

for my $value (sort { $a cmp $b } keys %{ $sort{program} }) {
    my @pids = grep $process_details{$_}{memory} > 2000,
               keys %{ $sort{program}{$value} };
    say join ' ', $_, @{ $process_details{$_} }{@COLUMNS}
        for @pids;
}

__DATA__
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  print if (split)[1] > 2000;
}

__DATA__
1 4730 1031782 init
4 0 6 events
2190 450 0 top
21413 5928 1 sshd
22355 1970 2009 find
```

With no arguments, `split()` splits `$_` on whitespace (which is what we want). We can then use a list slice to look at the second element of that and print the line if that value is greater than 2000.